Scaling Heavy Writes When Fetching Data From External API
I have a service that fetches financial data from an external APIs and parses and saves that data in a postgres DB. The data can be quite large in size, our containers have crashed quite a lot due to the sheer size of the data. For example if we have N merchants and each merchant is onboarded on M platforms we have to Fetch the data N*M times. We have a job that runs once a day for each merchant and each provider and calls the third party API to fetch the data.
Currently it's a simple service that fetches the data in bulk and writes the data to the db after fetching it, and since it's financial data consistency is required (though we can deal with eventual consistency in this case). And since we are dealing with archaic third party APIs the APIs are not always paginated so we have to fetch the data in bulk.
How can I scale it up to avoid crashing the service and to minimize the database load while maintaining the consistency requirements. Currently the data fetching takes hours to complete as we have to time the jobs to not overload the database, how can I optimize times as well?
I was thinking of using something like Kafka to control the DB writes and to break down the writes into chunks but maintaining consistency doing this is a lot of work.
Any suggestions as welcome. Thanks :)

exactly how much data are we talking?

A merchant can have around 20k transactions a day, and we get all the transaction info for those 20k transactions and then we repeeat it for M providers and N merchants.

i mean in Gigabytes. there 86400 seconds in a day so 20k transactions isnt alot

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

it seems weird that your container would crash, what's happening?

It is good that you're thinking about consistency, but that doesn't require that you write everything in one go. If using an ACID DB, start a transaction, then write each bit of data as you receive it. Finally, commit the tx. Otherwise, perhaps you can write to a staging area that is not yet used by live queries that need consistency. Append-only designs might be helpful. The banking system itself runs on fairly relaxed consistency, with transactions taking anywhere from seconds to days to settle. Perhaps you too can embrace this in your system.

@amon Maybe I misunderstand your point here but I think the question states that the data has to be retrieved in bulk.  The biggest challenge I see here is making sure every transaction is captured exactly once.  If transactions can be modified or appended to, that might present additional complexity.

I can fill up any amount of memory with the same character. Can you reliably reproduce this crash on demand? First find a way to do that and it'll make diagnosing the problem much easier.

tl;dr: Break this "too big" problem into smaller chunks.


and saves that data in a postgres DB.

Good!
You are building atop an excellent foundation.

our containers have crashed quite a lot due to the sheer size of the data.

I think you're saying, "sometimes we malloc() more than the container is provisioned for."
I also hear you saying, "this layer does not have a written specification
for chunk size, nor for allowable RAM usage."
Fix the specification problem first.
Write one down, adhere to it, learn as you go, revise it as needed.
Streaming from a non-paginated API endpoint to a .CSV file
or to a postgres temp table should not be an issue.
It completes within a second or within an hour, whatever,
depending on size of query result.
Adjusting the amount of provisioned RAM + swap space
sounds like another knob you can tune.

if we have N merchants and each merchant is onboarded on M platforms we have to fetch the data N × M times.

That aspect of your question is unclear, but let's move on.
I would think that either the API endpoint unavoidably expands a merchant's data
by a factor of M, or you could locally cache the merchant's 20k transactions
and expand each one by a factor of M when dealing with each onboarded platform.
Your subsequent remark suggests that required work
is proportional not to N × M, but to N + M.

We have a job that runs once a day for each merchant and each provider

Now we're getting to the heart of it.
It sounds like this is an undesirably coarse granularity, which causes some grief.
Query more frequently, perhaps hourly.
Then you have a smaller problem to solve, with less memory pressure.
Or perhaps the unspecified 3rd-party API only makes data available after midnight.
So wait until then, and issue a query for 9am .. 9:59am, then a
query for 10am, 11am, until close-of-business.
Again, smaller problems which consume less memory,
even when querying a non-paginated endpoint.
Having assembled some hourly snapshots in a temp table,
you're now in a better position to let postgres solve a "whole day" problem.
And you've pushed the memory management issue into the DB backend,
so that it is no longer your problem to worry about.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer the question. You point about not having spec for the containers hits the spot, this is the first thing I am going to do, performance test the containers and check their limits and have a spec for the containers.
Clarifying the NXM issue, each merchant has M payment providers mapped to them, so we need to fetch the data from all M payment providers for a merchant, this makes it a NxM problem.

the third party exposes the data after a specific time but all at once, I don't quite understand your point dividing the query into small parts by issuing the query at different times, even if I issue the query at different times the third party apis make the full data available, are you suggesting reading the data chunk by chunk by making same api call repeatedly?

The OP offered few details. I assumed “crash” meant “too much malloc”. I assumed your app doesn’t leak. I assumed at least one of the NxM API queries for past 24 hours returned “big” results. I assumed requesting 24 one-hour slices would turn that into “small” results which fit in the provisioned container. // As soon as possible, persist the query results and free up the RAM.
